# Photo Competion: February - Freezing Cold

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

### Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content

---

### Rules for February are as follows:

1. **All pictures must have been taken in the outdoors when the temperature was below freezing.**
2. No entries/photos should be posted before the beginning of February 2019, voting will be applicable until the final second of February and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

### Suggest theme for next month

1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format ->
     THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh now, my nicest winter pictures were taken while it was thawing :D

Comment: Theme --  Fauna;  Description -- Picture should be of a free non-domestic animal in either a wild or non-wild setting; no people.

Comment: Theme -- Deserts; Description -- Pics taken in a desert.

Comment: Theme -- Action:  A picture of a person in motion (or attempting to move - yes, you, climbers!)

Comment: Theme -- Animals gone wild -- Pictures of wild animals interacting poorly with people and their things (i.e bears in cars, geese chasing people)

Comment: Theme -- People -- Pictures of people you've met when you travel.

Comment: Theme -- Equipment: A picture of your favorite outdoor equipment/gear, preferably without people.

Comment: Theme -- Trees: Most of the trees are best, but the best trees you have seen are winners, preferably without people.

Comment: Themes -- Cloud/Sky: People living in the cities with tall building miss out on a lot when nature paints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## First pitch of Green Gully on Ben Nevis

Taken at 10:40 am GMT, Monday 14th March 2005.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## Tent message

28 December 1992.  Somebody evidently happened by my wild camp [in the Kirriereoch forest](//www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=55.1601860&mlon=-4.5350600&zoom=14) (in Galloway) whilst I spent the day on the Merrick, and was clearly not envious!

[image: Tent message]

Answer (score 9):

My friend Mat working up the first pitch of [Idwal Stream](https://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/c.php?i=40296) (II/III 4) (Cwm Idwal, Snowdonia, Wales) 3 Feb 2019. Conditions weren't ideal (with raising temps though the day) but an early start meant we were first on and in the coldest weather, making this the best pitch of the day.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Looking south from the top of Mt. Wheeler, with the sun just coming up.

Answer (score 6):

I arrived home from a week in 25C temperatures in China, to -5C in Scotland, which did make for a very pretty effect on my Subaru.

Taken 11:30 1 Feb 2019 at Edinburgh Airport.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Ben Nevis

Walking a compass bearing on the summit plateau having climbed Green Gully on 14th March 2005.

[image]

Comment: I've only just realised the optical illusion here.  Although I took this picture from behind, as we walked, I can mentally flip it so it looks like my partner is walking towards me.  I'd never noticed that before.

Answer (score 5):

This picture was taken on 2-2-2013 during the annual volunteer weekend where a packed trail is established on a stream in the Groulx Mountains. Every year it is cold, but this one was special. The temperature wouldn't rise above -40°C during the day for the whole weekend. Any moisture froze on contact, as can be seen here on Eric's face.

[image: It was frigid cold, and it shows]

Answer (score 5):

[image: A porch with ice on it.]
Taken October 2009, Mount Washington, New Hampshire, USA.
The first real cold of the year, they said. It was really freezing.

I had forgotten I had this photo, it was just when I checked my photos on Flickr that I remembered.

Answer (score 4):

### Deep Snow

Taken in 2003 at White Pass in Washington state.

[image: 2003 White pass Deep snow]

Answer (score 3):

Picture taken on February 03, 2019 at giants ridge in Biwabik Minnesota. This picture is of the view from the ski lift looking out over the forest.

[image: view from a chair lift]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Looking northeast just after summiting Mt. Wheeler, the highest peak in Nevada.

Comment: When was it taken?  Question asks for the date as well as location and subject.